# the file is open in IIS Worker Process

Tags: wcf, iis-7, file-rename, worker-process

I have a WCF service hosted on IIS7. I am using source control tool (IBM RTC) to manage code base and continuous deployment on our testing server. but my deployment is failing because IIS has acquired lock on log file.

Error message:

```
The command "ren "<some service path on network share>" ""<to path on network share>""" exited with code 1.
```

When I debug the issue more, I found it is failing because of error "the file is open in IIS Worker Process".

During the deployment, I am renaming old deployment folder with "_old" keyword and creating a new folder with new binaries.

How can I force IIS to release lock on log file.

Comment: Can't you just stop the AppDomain the webservice is running in and then do the rename? For example with [appcmd](http://serverfault.com/questions/155973/how-do-you-start-stop-iis-7-app-pool-from-cmd-line-if-there-are-spaces-in-the-ap)

Comment: If I stop AppDomain/application, it works fine but this is manual process and our deployment is completely automatic.  I want to do it from MS Build project itself.

Comment: You can do [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) from msbuild and let psexec run appcmd on that webserver. make sure that the user that execute psexec has permission to run appcmd.